# Why do we need to use $scope here?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("someawesomemodule", []);

    app.factory('data', function(){
        return { sometest: 'x' };
    });

    app.controller("FirstController", function( $scope, data ) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.data.sometest = "a";
    });
})
```

Why this doesn't work?

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("someawesomemodule", []);

    app.factory('data', function(){
        return { sometest: 'x' };
    });

    app.controller("FirstController", function( data ) {
        data.sometest = "a";
    });
})
```

What is $scope..?

Comment: @scope is the "global" variable

Comment: First example, you are binding your `'data'` Service to controller's `$scope` and then changing `Data`'s `Sometest` Property to `x`, which then gets updated in the `$scope` of your controller. Second example, you are just changing your `Data`'s `Sometest` Property without binding it to the `$scope`, so you cannot access it in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

$scope is glue between the view and your controller. If u want to share datas between these you have to use.But you can use this syntax:

```
app.controller("FirstController", function( data ) {
        this.data.sometest = "a";
    });
```

But this is not the best scenario:) Best way use $scope:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module("someawesomemodule", []);

    app.factory('data', function(){
        return { sometest: 'x' };
    });

    app.controller("FirstController", function( $scope, data ) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.data.sometest = "a";
    });
})
```

In the view:

```
<div ng-controller="FirstController">
    {{data.sometest}}
</div>
```

[This](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) will be a good start to think about Scope and Angular JS. If you start learning AngularJS start reading tutorials in Angular JS page after that read some design stuff like [this](https://github.com/trochette/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices)

Answer (score 1):

$scope is a container that holds the data for a controller. $scope's are not available to other controllers directly so it's useful for keeping separation between your parts of code. Views can only access controller data if it's been added to $scope.

```
var myGreatVariable;
```

not available to view yet...

```
$scope.myVar = myGreatVariable;
```

View can now access variable and display it like this:

```
{{ myVar }}
```

There exists a global scope shared by all controllers that inject it called $rootScope. You should not use $rootScope too often as more likely than not you actually want a service for this.

```
app.controller("SomeController", function( $rootScope ) {
    $rootScope.userId = 123;
});

app.controller("SomeController", function( $scope, UserService ) {
    $scope.userId = UserService.id;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### What is $scope

`$scope` is the glue between your controller(s) and your views. It is what holds the data that is bound into your UI/markup.

Items that you place into the `$scope` in your controller are available to utilize in your markup, this includes values and functions.

`$rootScope` is the parent of all scopes in your app via parent/child relationships.

### Why doesn't it work

The real reason you can not use this is `Dependency Injection` angular's dependency injection engine does lookups based upon strings (name of the parameters) in the order which they appear, which is why you'll see these two syntaxes:

```
module.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){});
module.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){}]);
```

Both are valid, but the first one will break if you minified/uglify your code because `$scope` will get renamed, but `'$scope'` will not.

So when you change `$scope` to `data` angular does not know what to pass into your controller.

Comment: this is correct -- Angular's DI gives the controller `$scope` as the first param. So - if you changed the first argument to `foo` (or something/anything) and then made `data` any argument thereafter, the `data` argument should contain the data stuffs.

Comment: apparently - i am wrong. the parameter is matched by name.

Answer (score 0):

The scope is described on the angular developer guide. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts